# Chrome addon to open link in new tab to the right of the current tab

Tags: chrome, productivity

Using Chrome, we can open links in new tabs either via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Click</kbd> or <kbd>Right-click</kbd><kbd>Open link in new tab</kbd>:

[image]

The new tab is **not** guaranteed to open to the immediate right-hand side of the parent tab. For those interested in the odd algorithm Chrome uses, :

> By default, Chrome will open the new tab at the immediate right-hand side of the rightmost tab among the *chained* (i.e. connected side-by-side without ever being unconnected) unclosed tabs that had been opened by the current tab which has never been moved to another window. (It's an *art* trying to figure out exactly where the new tab will open to, especially when tabs are often dragged around. /s)
>
> Contrast that with the behavior of <kbd>Highlight text</kbd><kbd>Right-click</kbd><kbd>Search Google for '`x`'</kbd> which will **always** open the new tab at the **immediate** right-hand side of the parent tab.

Is there a Chrome addon to change the behavior of 'Open link in new tab' such that it will always open the new tab to the immediate right-hand side of the parent tab?  (To be clear, the only thing that changes is the position of the new tab. Everything else remains the same.)

Currently I'm manually dragging those off-positioned new tabs, wasting quite a couple of precious hours (over the years). Another equally time-consuming way is to drag the tab to the left then to the right (or vice-versa) before clicking on the new link.

Comment: It has taken some time, but my experience of the new tabs are that when opening new tabs from a parent tab a new group is created immediately to the right of my parent tab. Then after that, the new tab (from the same parent tab is added to the right within that group. Kind of strange, but there is a system in it, and I'm getting used to it... What I'm saying is perhaps, try to learn to love it?!

Comment: On my Mac you can use `Shift+Ctrl+Middle-click` to open a windows to the immediate right, but it does also shift focus to the new tab, which maybe isn't what you want. But maybe you then could use a short cut to get back (i.e. `Fn+Ctrl+Up`), and that is a better total solution?

Comment: @holroy, I wouldn't mind loving it if it doesn't reduce productivity by nontrivial noticeable amounts.... Btw, couldn't test the middle click functionality here on Windows. All three of my mice are strictly dual-button only.

Answer (score 4):

### [Tabs Plus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabsplus/nikomkkhhpfoeamojhhgpfkpkdlfhfii)

This extension provides a very easy-to-use and understand control panel for you to change the behaviour of opening new tabs:

[image]

The 'position of a new tab' is the setting you want here. It makes all new tabs, no matter when they originate from open *next to* the current tab.

You can see in the screenshot that there are more options as well - you can change these if you want, or just leave them as-is to keep the default procedure Chrome has :)

**Note:** It seems the developer has abandoned this extension - as it has not been updated since 24th June 2013!

Comment: There are two ways to open a new tab: 1) Ctrl-T and 2) the '+' button at the extreme right side of the tabsbar. Ctrl-T is working as expected (opens to the next right), but is there any way to make it such that if we click on the '+' button, the new tab opens to the **rightmost** tab (which means the default behavior)?

Comment: @Pacerier sorry - I don't think so :(

Comment: I've found a **serious bug** with this problem. It only affects the first window. 'Open to Next Right' doesn't work with the other windows. Is the bug affecting your system too?

Comment: @Pacerier hmmm you're right - it doesn't work on new windows! You might want to report that to the author!

Comment: Hmm, [I've reported it](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabsplus/nikomkkhhpfoeamojhhgpfkpkdlfhfii/support). But looks like someone else has reported this problem since 2013 Jun 26. I don't think the author is working on it anymore.

Comment: @Pacerier hmm.. it seems so :(. I've added so in the answer to warn other users!

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Ctrl + Shift + Mouse Left Click** to always open tab very next to the current tab.

Also You will directly land on the newly opened tab.